# Adding an item in list in flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

Hi guys i have a list control in a component mxml file. I have created a function in main mxml file, i want to input a text string and add it to this list. How can i do that. Currently using this code

```
public function add(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var name:String = mytextinputid.text;
            currentState = 'ChatScreen';
                mylist.____     
        }
```

Note that this function is in main and the mylist list control is in component mxml

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have assigned an id to your component, which I assume is mylist, you simply call

```
myList.dataProvider.addItem(name);
```

You should always have a `dataProvider` set to myList. Or else you can set one at run time.

```
var myCollection:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
myCollection.addItem(name);
myList.dataProvider = myCollection;
```

OR you can specify a `dataProvider` from MXML

```
<mx:List id="myList" dataProvider="{myCollection}"/>
```

Comment: ok thanks for that but how can i access the list.dataprovider when the list is in component mxml and the function in which i want to call it is in main.mxml

Comment: Well the component has an id as well right? You can access it like, `myComponent.myList.dataProvider`. If this doesn't answer your question, I suggest you show us your code on how the component and the main is related.

Comment: i have a main.mxml in which i have a button and a text box, i want to input the text and then click on button to add it in list. now the list is in a mxml group component file named as panel.mxml. now using button i can call a function that adds the string witten in text box

Comment: i tried giving id to it , gives error that cant give id at root tag

Comment: You need to give id for panel.mxml file in mxml. Then you can acces it's children from outside like "yourPanel.mydatagrid.dataProvider = yourData;" Remember, if you bind arrayCollection to some controls as dataProvider, it must be declared as a bindable metatags.